# Conditional list of tables in LaTex

Tags: table-of-contents, conditionals

List of Tables can be obtained by using `listoftables` commands. I wonder how to skip `listoftables` output if the document doesn't contain any table. Thanks

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoftables

\clearpage

\section{Dummy section 1}


\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Dummy table 1}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}

\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\label{tab:dum1}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A possible way is to use the table counter

`\ifnum\value{table} > 0 \listoftables \fi` wouldn't work alone since the number of tables isn't known at that stage of processing. With the `totcounter` package one could register the total number of tables (which is written to the `.aux` file (so it's known in the second run finally). 
However, since the table counter might be in the reset list of `chapter` or `section` counter (depends on other settings), the (total) table counter might have a value of zero. Therefore I used (my ;-)) `assoccnt` package which counts the number of tables differently.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{assoccnt}
\usepackage{totcount}

\newtotcounter{tottables}
\DeclareAssociatedCounters{table}{tottables}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\ifnum\totvalue{tottables} > 0 
\listoftables
\fi

\IfFileExists{\jobname.lot}{%
 \listoftables
}{%
 % Does not exist
}

\clearpage

\section{Dummy section 1}


\begin{table}[ht]
%\caption{Dummy table 1}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}

\end{tabular}

\label{tab:dum1}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Please use `\centering`.

Comment: @Johannes_B: That's the O.P. code, not mine ;-)